# Adjusting the relative offset in array modifier is not giving exact results

Tags: modifiers

As you can see in the picture i have added a array modifier to the cylinder to make holes for rings in the album

I have given exact number of count as rings and trying to match the cylinders that can match each ring

But when i tried to adjust the factor of Y in relative offset i am unable to match as i want because one cylinder goes up and one goes down than the rings

What should i do to match the rings for holes

[image]

Just now i tried Shift+R to get equal distances by removing the array modifier but still the distance is not matching

[image]

Comment: have you tried to type the value manually?

Comment: Ya, i have given a value of 2.15478 by typing but still not accurate

Comment: then maybe scale a bit?

Comment: Ya, it worked but a hefty process of increasing and checking, has to be some better process in future

Comment: You should use a constant offset. Find the exact distance between each hole center on the notebook and then set the Constant offset value to that amount. Relative offset means you're basing the distance between each ring to it's overall size.

Comment: When you are using _Relative Offset_ on both the rings and the cylinders you have to either make sure that they are the exact same size or you have to calculate the size relations to each other, so that they move the same distance per step like _offset B_ = _offset A_ * (_size A_ / _size B_).